# How can I enable/disable Dash online results programmatically?

Tags: command-line, unity-dash, automation, dconf, gsettings

How can I change this setting from a Bash script?

[image: System Settings ▸ Privacy ▸ Search Results ▸ When searching in the Dash: Include online search results]

My plan is to enable it only on certain network connections.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `dconf-editor` to change this setting.  It's under:

```
com -> canonical -> unity -> lenses
```

and is called `remote-content-search`. As far as I know there are only two options `none` and `all`.  When set to `all` the slider is set to "On" in system settings and when it is set to `none` the slider is at the "Off" position.

You can change this via the terminal using `gsettings`.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search all
```

Will turn it on while:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search none
```

will set it to "Off".

Gsettings comes by default in Ubuntu and you can install dconf with:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

You don't need dconf to use gsettings.